# Custom post type as child of page

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, routing

I am wondering if it's possible to have a page, let's say called 'books' with some listed books.

Next to this normal page we create an custom post named 'books' were we collect our books.

Nou I already have the url domain.com/books/ with the overview of all my books, I am wondering how I need to configure the custom post to use this page as parent to generate an url as domain.com/books/the-title-of-the-book/

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, do you want posts of a custom post type to have a manually created page as their parent? As opposed to an automatically created archive that lists posts of post type 'book'?

Comment: Yes, what I actually want is /book (page)/%slug%(custom_post_type)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I had to fiddle with permalinks for some time for my library plugin [WP-Librarian](https://github.com/kittsville/WP-Librarian), so I think I know the answer. I'll just check if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your custom post type listed under a page you can add the permalink of the page to the rewrite slug like so:

```
register_post_type('my_books', array(
'has_archive' => false,                 // Stops domain.com/book becoming the cpt's archive
'rewrite'     => array('slug' => 'book')
));
```

You need to visit `Settings->Permalinks` after making any changes to permalinks to re-generate them. You should now be able to visit books under `mysite.com/book/my-book-slug` and visit your manually created Page under `mysite.com/book`.

Comment: Works m8! The only thing is that it points at my index.php now. I didn't reserve this page for the index as the index has been pointed to a page-hone.php, could you think about any reasons for this?

Comment: Not too sure what's causing that, when I tested that setup on my dev server it worked. If you tried other things first and left the code in then it may be interfearing.

Comment: fixed it out, I created a page 'books' instead of page-books and this was the trick :)